# Coreml model float input for a pytorch model

Tags: python, ios, pytorch, coreml, onnx-coreml

I have a pytorch model that takes `3 x width x height` image as input with the pixel values normalized between `0-1`

E.g., input in pytorch

```
img = io.imread(img_path)
input_img =  torch.from_numpy( np.transpose(img, (2,0,1)) ).contiguous().float()/255.0
```

I converted this model to coreml and exported an mlmodel which takes the input with correct dimensions

```
Image (Color width x height)
```

However, my predictions are incorrect as the model is expecting a float value between `0-1` and cvpixelbuffer is a int bwetween `0-255`

I tried to normalize the values inside the model like so,

```
z = x.mul(1.0/255.0) # div op is not supported for export yet
```

However, when this op is done inside model at coreml level,  `int * float` is casted as `int` and all values are essentially `0`

Cast op is not supported for export e.g., `x = x.float()`

How can I make sure my input is properly shaped for prediction? Essentially, I want to take the `pixel rgb and float divide 255.0` and pass it to the model for inference?

Comment: Can you provide more code for your problem? And why is "cast op not supported"? That seems very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the coreml onnx coverter's preprocessing_args like so,

```
preprocessing_args= {'image_scale' : (1.0/255.0)}
```

Hope this helps someone